# WPF Image, how to remove blur?

Tags: wpf, image-processing, wpf-controls

I have [image]

I need [image]

XAML:

```
<Image Height="500"
       MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown"
       MouseRightButtonDown="image_MouseRightButtonDown"
       Name="image"
       Stretch="Fill"
       Width="500" />`
```

C#:

```
  wbmap = new WriteableBitmap(50, 50, 500, 500, PixelFormats.Indexed8, palette);
  wbmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, wbmap.PixelWidth, wbmap.PixelHeight), pixels, wbmap.PixelWidth * wbmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8, 0);
  image.Source = wbmap;
```

Comment: Please give more details!. How did you get that Blur in the first image? Was that generated in XAML?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As tkerwin mentioned, change the [BitmapScalingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode.aspx) to `NearestNeighbor` in you XAML Image code:

```
RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
```

Comment: I tried to use the code above. It works fine! But I can not find in MSDN where Image.RenderOptions is described, there is no info on the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx . Where the doc can be found? Thanks

Comment: @sergdev - The `RenderOptions` class can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms635510)

Comment: I see, I saw that page, thanks. I try to clarify: where is relation between Image and RenderOptions class described? I thought that RenderOptions is a member of Image, but this is not the case. Just can not realize how to undestand this from MSDN.

Comment: @sergdev - There isnt a relationship per se, the `RenderOptions` is a static class (all by itself).

Comment: @sergdev it looks ".BitmapScalingMode" is a DependencyProperty -- so it can be assigned to any DependencyObject.  (You could assign it to all sorts of things that don't make any sense -- like Rectangles, for example. -- for the objects that don't recognize the property, it just gets ignored.)

Comment: Now it has to be             RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(this,BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);

Answer (score 19):

Perhaps you need to change the bitmap scaling mode to nearest neighbor.

Add `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"` to your Image tag.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer is considered to have less of a code example than the accepted answer.  That's kind of messed up. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Increase resolution / scale without anti-aliasing.

Whats happening is WPF is scaling the image but "averaging" the pixels, rather than doing a more blocky scale.

See this post:

[Resize bitmap like in MS Paint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854306/resize-bitmap-like-in-ms-paint/1856362#1856362)

Comment: I have image with 50x50 resolution in 500x500 Image control. I want image without anti-aliasing. How can i get it?